# Using jxmaps for tracking

Tags: java, jxmaps

i'm developing a java desktop application for tracking device like PC,
My code is based on examples giving in https://www.teamdev.com/jxmaps#code
Please how can i get current position 
thanks

Comment: What platform are you running your code on?  Windows? Mac? Linux? Android?  Bear in mind that many computers are not capable of giving their location.

Comment: i'm running my code on Windows

Comment: Does your hardware have geolocation capability?

Comment: yes my hardware have geolocation capability

Comment: OK.  So search for "java windows gps".  You will need to use another library to get your current position.  There are many possible options.

Comment: thank you so much , i'll check that

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, current version of JxMaps doesn't provide possibility to get current location. But you can use any third party solution to get coordinates of current position and pass them to LatLng objects.